# Server Configuration Interpretation

Tags: central-processing-unit

I wants to understand lscpu command output.

CPU(s):                4 (Shows total number of CPU's)
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3 - (CPU sequence)
Thread(s) per core:    2 - ? 
Core(s) per socket:    2 - ?
Socket(s):             1 - ?

As I know Socket is slot on CPU to hold CPU so its bit confused 4 CPU's have 1 Socket and should not it be 4 Socket like 1 Socket for each CPU.

Please help me to understand above configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to see the original output, not your weird interpretation of it.

From what I can understand:

- your server  have one CPU socket populated
- it has one CPU in it with two cores
- it's capable of two threads per core
- it gives you 4 logical CPUs

After all `ls` displays the CPU model, which can clarify lots of your questions.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. So 1 Socket = 1 CPU , Threads per core = 2 and cores per socket = 2 means there are 2 cores with CPU capable of 2 threads per core but what about 4 logical CPU's

Comment: nothing. I explained everything you were asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets: Physical CPUs - 1 socket = 1 physical CPU

Cores per Socket: Your CPU has 2 cores

Threads per Core: Your CPU has 2. This looks like a HT CPU.

CPUs 0 - 3: these are CPU threads 0, 1, 2, and 3